# How to update monitoring window(listview) after each 5 seconds in android

Tags: android

I am getting data from a url for the monitoring window which show the list of visitors visiting the site,along with their ip,session id,time to live to site,no. of visit and their status from that url.i have to show data in a listview and after each 5 seconds getting new data.how can i make the listview that set data getting from url and after each 5 seconds update the data getting from server(means each after 5 seconds add new data to list).

can anyone help me?

I am using the update method like following.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
 Runnable updater = new Runnable() {

     public void run() {

       /*
        * Update the list 
        */




         getVisitorDetailFromServer();





       try {
          Log.i("UPDATE", "Handler called");
         // searchAdapter = getFeed(URL);

          handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);

       } catch(Exception e) {
          Log.e("UPDATE ERROR", e.getMessage());
       }

      }

     };

        updater.run();
```

i am getting data correctly now using this method but problem is that after some time app is being crashed java.lang.indexoutofboundsexception occurs.

Comment: What you have tried till now and what problem you are facing?

Comment: from getVisitorDetailFromServer() i am getting data from server that is being added in listview.once i set the data i am renewing the arraylists.my app is being crashed after sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use scheduled timer , you can use this code:

```
private Timer myTimer;
myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TimerMethod();
                }

            }, 0, 10000); 
        }

    }
    private void TimerMethod()
    {
        //This method is called directly by the timer
        //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

        //We call the method that will work with the UI
        //through the runOnUiThread method.
        this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);

    } 

    private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               

        //Do something to the UI thread here


        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

just try notifydatasetchange on list view. Run a  thread and in that just do adater.notifydatasetchange.

Comment: TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
  {
   @Override
   public void run()
   {

    updateList();

   }


  };
  timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000);

Comment: i want my listview updated add new items each after 5 seconds whenever get new data from server

Answer (score 0):

try method below:

1 put your data in array or database or anyelse, which related to listview's adapter

2 create a Handler and use sendMessageDelaed(Message,5000) or postDelayed(Runnable,5000) to compose a loop.

3 call adapter.notifyDatasetChange(); in Runnable or handleMessage

in all, what you should do is update the dataset and call notifydatasetchange every 5 seconds.(Also can use TimerTask or other method)

Comment: thanks.i used this but my listview is not refreshing i am getting data from server new each after 5 seconds.i want as soon as got new data listview updated with new data just like monitoring window any any livechat in which list of visitor list updated automatically after few seconds.

Comment: every get new data call notifyDatasetChange() doesn't work?  where do you save the data, try to call setAdapter(adapter); again after get new data

Answer (score 0):

See, if the datastructure (arraylist or other) containig your data is changing, ie. you are doing 
*"Your_ARRAY_LIST" = new ArrayList();*
every time you get new data from the server, "notifyDataSetChanged()" **wont** work, 
as what it does is that it notifies the adapter that the arraylist containg data has been updated and the adapter then tries to refresh the data from the same address.
But in your case the address of the data structure would have been changed.
So if you are doing this, you need to set the adapter again in the "update()" method of your timertask.

Comment: i am using this method as you said and in update method again setting the adapter my application is being crashed and also renewing the arraylist but my app is being crashed.

Comment: you can share the file either through www.pastebin.com